# Error: Couldn't find constructor 'ThemeData'

Tags: flutter, dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',

      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
    
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
       
        child: Column(
        
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

The error is shown below.
This error is not only for this app. In all codes, the error shown below is displayed when I try to run the code.

```
    ../../../../app/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/theme_data.dart(240,11): error G90CBB506: The name of a constructor must match the name of the enclosing class. [C:\Users\JEBA\Documents\edu\3rd\flutter\form\build\windows\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
lib/main.dart(6,28): error GF7CA4DBF: Couldn't find constructor 'ThemeData'. [C:\Users\JEBA\Documents\edu\3rd\flutter\form\build\windows\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
../../../../app/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/snack_bar.dart(450,75): error GF7CA4DBF: Couldn't find constructor 'ThemeData'. [C:\Users\JEBA\Documents\edu\3rd\flutter\form\build\windows\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
../../../../app/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/theme_data.dart(927,12): error GF7CA4DBF: Couldn't find constructor 'ThemeData'. [C:\Users\JEBA\Documents\edu\3rd\flutter\form\build\windows\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
../../../../app/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/theme_data.dart(952,32): error GF7CA4DBF: Couldn't find constructor 'ThemeData'. [C:\Users\JEBA\Documents\edu\3rd\flutter\form\build\windows\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
../../../../app/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/theme_data.dart(958,31): error GF7CA4DBF: Couldn't find constructor 'ThemeData'. [C:\Users\JEBA\Documents\edu\3rd\flutter\form\build\windows\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Preview\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(245,5): error MSB8066: Custom build for 'C:\Users\JEBA\Documents\edu\3rd\flutter\form\build\windows\CMakeFiles\8c26996d31721dd8e16c4d3086d88a31\flutter_windows.dll.rule;C:\Users\JEBA\Documents\edu\3rd\flutter\form\build\windows\CMakeFiles\44b2ac0b613f8eecec5611123150db21\flutter_assemble.rule;C:\Users\JEBA\Documents\edu\3rd\flutter\form\windows\flutter\CMakeLists.txt' exited with code 1. [C:\Users\JEBA\Documents\edu\3rd\flutter\form\build\windows\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
Building Windows application...                                         
Exception: Build process failed.
```

[image]Flutter run, displays this error. The code is initially generated counter app.

I have tried flutter clean and flutter pub get. but it doesn't work.
and I have tried to run the app on different devices. All attempts I have tried is failed.

Comment: Please show the code and also the error message as text using the Code Sample option.

Comment: @WilsonToribio I have added the code above.

Comment: Would you please provide the version of Dart and flutter you have?

Comment: @WilsonToribio - Flutter 2.11.0-0.1.pre • channel dev 
- Framework • revision b101bfe32f (7 weeks ago) • 2022-02-16 07:36:54 -0800
- Engine • revision e355993572 
- Tools • Dart 2.17.0 (build 2.17.0-69.2.beta) • DevTools 2.10.0-dev.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow this steps:

1. Go to `theme_data.dart` by clicking ctrl + the error in the
   Debug Console.
2. Change the name FThemeData to ThemeData as shown [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgPR5.jpg
3. Save and run your code

Comment: Renaming core libs is misleading.